# Is there an API for Cardano Blockchain Insights?

Tags: api

I'm looking for any API or any source that would allow me to export data & statistics?
(Specifically Blockchain load per day)

I found that [DataStudio](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/3136c55b-635e-4f46-8e4b-b8ab54f2d460/page/p_wxcw6g0irc) has stats, yet it doesn't have any export options.

And I found that [Blockfrost](https://blockfrost.io) also has an API but I didn't find Blockchain load per day option there.

Cheers

Comment: You should upvote the answer when you accept it.

Comment: @gRebel I don't have enough reputation to upvote answers, however I did tag it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to run a node or services yourself you can use https://api.koios.rest/#overview

If you run your own node or are friendly with someone who does you can use DB-Sync.

DB-Sync is a PostgreSQL relational DB of Cardano blockchain data.

You can query it using standard SQL.

DB-Sync:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync

DB Schema:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/schema.md

Example queries:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/interesting-queries.md

Docs:
https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-components/cardano-db-sync

Comment: Thanks a lot :)